# Como se usa la funcion $emit en Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estoy usando como librería **Vue.js** tengo el caso de usar un componente que llama a otros componentes la pregunta es como puedo emitir una función al hacer una acción dentro de mi componente hijo.

ejemplo:
  que al hacer `click` en el componente hijo cambie la data del componente padre.

Ya estoy usando vuex pero mi pregunta es si se puede cambiar directamente la data del componente padre con la acción del componente hijo espero hacerme entender muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay que agregar la función `$emit` a un evento del componente hijo que, a su vez, ejecuta un evento del padre. En este caso, al hacer `click` emitimos a la función `funcionLlamadaDesdeHijo()` que nos cambia el texto de la data `mensaje`.

Saludos espero les ayude.

```js
var componenteHijo = {
  template:`
  <div>
    <button type="button" name="button">No tiene la funcion $emit de vue</button>
    
    <button type="button" name="button" @click="$emit('click','Cambio la data por la emision del componente hijo')">Emitir cambio al data padre</button>
    </div>
  `
}

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    mensaje: 'Hola mundo'
  },
  components:{
    componenteHijo
  },
  methods:{
    funcionLlamadaDesdeHijo(textoNuevo){
      this.mensaje = textoNuevo
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>
  {{ mensaje }}
  </h1>
  <br>
  <componente-hijo @click="funcionLlamadaDesdeHijo">
  </componente-hijo>
</div>
```